# want to find a good online Library Manual of C++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ from C. When I need to find something about c. I always type "man ***" on google then I can get what I want. But how can I find nice c++ library documentation?
Thanks..

Comment: What part of the C++ Standard Library?  The entire C Standard Library is included and you can use the same documentation.  The [SGI STL reference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/), while a little dated, is still by far the best reference for the STL components.  Whatever Standard Library implementation you are using should have comprehensive or near-comprehensive documentation as well.  For what other components do you need documentation?

Comment: I want to find something like this..    http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/open/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a reference, try:

http://cplusplus.com/reference/

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/